# Keeping en0 down while I change IP address mac

Tags: ip, python, terminal

I have a DHCP server which assigns myself a new IP address. What I'm wanting to do is power down the wireless adaptor, then change the ip address manually. What's happening is as soon as I set the new IP address, the device automatically powers up! I want it to stay powered down UNTIL I turn it back on.

What I do:

`sudo ifconfig en0 down` -- this turns off adaptor

`networksetup -setmanual "Wi-Fi" 192.168.1.98 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.254` -- this changes the address which is good but automatically powers it on!!

How can I change the ip address AND leave it powered on until I use something like `sudo ifconfig en0 up` ?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so it seems like using `sudo ifconfig en0 down` is not the best way to do it.

Best way is to turn off airport first
`sudo networksetup -setairportpower airport off`

then change the IP address to manual:
`sudo networksetup -setmanual "Wi-Fi" 192.168.1.98 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.254`

the device will still be turned off here so turn it back on and it should have same IP address as the one you set
`sudo networksetup -setairportpower airport on`